# Pegar o conteúdo das colunas que estão dentro de um while

Tags: sql

Boa noite! Estou tentando usar as colunas do segundo `while` para inserir em uma tabela, porém não consigo pegar o valor das colunas. Já utilizei várias combinações de aspas e nada. Isso é possível?

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @tag varchar(20), @tagnova varchar(20)
DECLARE @temp TABLE  (tag nvarchar(20))
DECLARE @temp2 TABLE (time datetime,point nvarchar(128),alm_type varchar(128),unit varchar(128),pv varchar(128),limit nvarchar(128))

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT tag FROM nas.dbo.tb_cadastro 

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT tag FROM @temp)

BEGIN

    SET @tag = (SELECT TOP 1 tag FROM @temp)

    SET @tagnova = SUBSTRING(@tag, 0, CHARINDEX('@', @tag))

    INSERT INTO @temp2
    SELECT Time,point,alm_type,unit,pv,limit FROM [EventHistDB].[dbo].[Event_val2] WHERE point = ''+@tagnova+'' and (kind = 'ALM') and (alm_type = 'PVHH' OR alm_type = 'PVLL')

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT Time as time, point as point, alm_type as alm_type, unit as unit, pv as pv, limit as limit FROM @temp2)

    BEGIN

        SET @query = 'INSERT INTO [nas].[dbo].[tb_eventos] (room, tag, excur_start, max_min, limite, tipo, unit) 
        VALUES (SUBSTRING('''+@tagnova+''', CHARINDEX(''_T'','''+@tagnova+''')+1, (LEN('''+@tagnova+''') - CHARINDEX(''_T'','''+@tagnova+''')))
        ,'''+@tag+'''
        ,time
        ,pv
        ,limit
        ,alm_type
        ,unit)';

        print (@query)

    END

    DELETE FROM @temp WHERE tag = @tag;

END
```

Comment: Já tentou usar um TRIGGER? Com ele é possível manipular os dados utilizados no comando.

Comment: Fala em substituir o set por um TRIGGER? Vou pesquisar como aplicar nesse caso.

Comment: Consegui resolver usando um cursor.